# How to solve this integral (right below)?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, residue-calculus

Show that:
$$
p.v.\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{(\omega' - \omega_0)^2 + a^2}\frac{1}{\omega' - \omega}d\omega' = 
\frac{\pi}{a}\frac{\omega - \omega_0}{(\omega - \omega_0)^2 + a^2}
$$

Where $p.v.$ is the principal value of the integral.

---

I suspect it has something to do with the "integral analog" of cauchy-riemann equations (below) which came from Cauchy Integral formula.
$$
f(x_0) = \frac{1}{\pi i}p.v.\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{u(x) + iv(x)}{x-x_0}dx
$$

One can separate the values of $u(x_0)$ and $v(x_0)$ separating real and imaginary parts from above formula.

$$
u(x_0) = \frac{1}{\pi}p.v\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{v(x)}{x-x_0}dx \\
v(x_0) = -\frac{1}{\pi}p.v\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{u(x)}{x-x_0}dx
$$

However.. I am really stuck from here.... Indeed, the answer seems really close to these relations... But, I have no idea how this helps to solve integral, because, integration under $v(x)$ will give $u(x_0)$ and so forth.

Any help? How to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\mathrm{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{1 \over \pars{\omega' - \omega_{0}}^2 + a^{2}}\,
{1 \over \omega' - \omega}\,\dd\omega'} =
\mathrm{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{1 \over \pars{\omega' - \Omega}^2 + a^{2}}\,
\,{\dd\omega' \over \omega'}\,,\quad\Omega \equiv \omega_{0} - \omega
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\mathrm{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{1 \over \pars{\omega' - \omega_{0}}^2 + a^{2}}\,
{1 \over \omega' - \omega}\,\dd\omega'}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\infty}
\bracks{{1 \over \pars{\omega' - \Omega}^2 + a^{2}} -
{1 \over \pars{-\omega' - \Omega}^2 + a^{2}}}\,{\dd\omega' \over \omega'}
\\[5mm] = &\
4\Omega\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\dd\omega' \over \bracks{\pars{\omega' - \Omega}^2 + a^{2}}
\bracks{\pars{\omega' + \Omega}^2 + a^{2}}} =
\\[5mm] = &\
2\Omega\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\dd\omega' \over \bracks{\pars{\omega' - \Omega}^2 + a^{2}}
\bracks{\pars{\omega' + \Omega}^2 + a^{2}}} =
2\Omega\bracks{{\pi\,\mathrm{sgn}\pars{a} \over 2a\pars{a^{2} + \Omega^{2}}}}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\\[5mm] & =
\color{#f00}{-\,{\pi \over \verts{a}}
{\omega - \omega_{0} \over \pars{\omega - \omega_{0}}^{2} + a^{2}}}
\end{align}

> The integral, in expression \eqref{1}, is evaluated by 'standard means'. For example, by a contour integration in the complex plane or by partial fraction expansion.